# VS 2010 C++ IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

Is it possible to add exceptions to IntelliSense to prevent complaints about statements it is unable to understand, for example `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT`?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off IntelliSense by right clicking on the error tab and removing the check box beside intellisense.